# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar

Tags: android

When using searchbar in layout, the program will crash immediately.

The layout is below

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/base_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"/>
        <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/display_list_view"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the basic theme
`Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`

Android API version: min 31; target 33

**Material Library version:**1.9.0

The detail error is below
by the way, I havn't declare the view in my activity yet.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.searchbar, PID: 7216
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.searchbar/com.example.searchbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.searchbar:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.searchbar:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3825)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3971)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8261)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.searchbar:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.searchbar:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.searchbar:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:883)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1035)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:990)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1152)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1113)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1155)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1113)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:711)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:548)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:486)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:469)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:3698)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.setContentView(ComponentActivity.java:448)
                                                                                                        at com.example.searchbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:38)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8516)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8480)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1418)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3971)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
2023-07-26 14:04:01.648  7216-7216  AndroidRuntime          com.example.searchbar  E    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8261)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar requires a value for the com.example.searchbar:attr/colorOnSurfaceVariant attribute to be set in your app theme. You can either set the attribute in your theme or update your theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialAttributes.resolveTypedValueOrThrow(MaterialAttributes.java:72)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialAttributes.resolveTypedValueOrThrow(MaterialAttributes.java:56)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.color.MaterialColors.getColor(MaterialColors.java:76)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar.maybeTintNavigationIcon(SearchBar.java:380)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar.setNavigationIcon(SearchBar.java:360)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar.initNavigationIcon(SearchBar.java:250)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar.<init>(SearchBar.java:190)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar.<init>(SearchBar.java:152)
```

I've tried to change my theme and it seemed not work.
But I dont know if I changed it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `colorOnSurfaceVariant` item in your theme like this:

```xml
<style name="ThemeName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
   ...
   <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">#FFFFFF</item>
   ....
</style>
```

Comment: I have a theme that inherits from a NoActionBar theme Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar, and it's still crashing with this solution.

Comment: Found that must be Theme.Material3... Thanks